# ayuda con codigo php json

Tags: php, json, web

Tengo este codigo php en json:

```html
 <?php
header('Content-type: application/json');?>{"br":[<?php
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://fortnitecontent-website-prod07.ol.epicgames.com/content/api/pages/fortnite-game?lang=it'), true);
/*var_dump($response);*/

     $count = count($response['battleroyalenews']['news']['motds']);
       
    $else = false;

$data = $response['battleroyalenews']['news']['motds'];

 for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
 $signature = current($data);


 echo '{"image":"';
 echo $data[$i]['image'] . '","title":"';
 echo $data[$i]['title'] . '","body":"';
 echo $data[$i]['body'] . '"},';

    next($response);
     
}
  
// Function to convert array into JSON 
echo  '{}]}'; 
?>
```

y lo que quiero quitar es...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando lo quito no me genera el codigo json  :(

Aquí dejo una vista previa:
https://todocodigos.000webhostapp.com/aesFortnite/a.php

Answer (score 5):

Ese ultimo {} se lo estas ingresando tu mismo en la ultima linea del codigo

```
// Function to convert array into JSON 
echo  '{}]}';
```

a

```
// Function to convert array into JSON 
echo  ']}';
```

Comment: Al quitarselo no se visualiza bien el codigo json: asi se ve quitado
https://i.imgur.com/0owh4rC.png

Sin quitar
https://i.imgur.com/NCCaH6e.png

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que si lo quitas, tu json queda al final con una `,` y eso en un formato json es un error.

Podrías hacer una condición para que si es el último elemento, no le ponga coma, o mejor aún hacer la respuesta con `echo json_encode($data_return);` donde `$data_return` es el arreglo a regresar

Lo que en tu código podría quedar como

```
$data = $response['battleroyalenews']['news']['motds'];
$data_return = [];

 for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
 $signature = current($data);
    $data_return[] = $data[$I];

    next($response);

}

// Function to convert array into JSON 
echo  json_encode($data_return);
```